# Why did AWS Pinpoint not deliver all my campaigns email messages?

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, amazon-ses, aws-pinpoint

Using the AWS console we sent a manual email campaign to a segment of 1000 users.

Looking at the campaign delivery metrics the day after the send, I have the following stats:

- 1,000 Messages sent
- 207 Messages delivered
- 20.7% Delivery rate
- 0.97% Bounce rate

Looking at the stats from Amazon SES we only sent 215 emails. Amazon says it calculates the messages delivered in the following way:

> The number of messages that were delivered to their intended
> recipients. Amazon Pinpoint calculates this number by subtracting the
> number of messages that bounced from Messages sent.

The 0.97% Bounce rate stat doesn't look like it calculates to a missing 800 emails. It should be a bounce rate of 75% to only have 207 deliveries. SES is saying we only sent 215 emails, so there are around 800 emails from the segment which were not sent.

Our account suppression list has around 200 emails, so worst case we should have sent 800 messages.

Why weren't the 800 emails sent? is there a way to find them in the stats? Again, though SES is only reporting 215 sends.

Comment: How long did you send this campaign for? It can take a while to send them all.

Comment: It was an immediate campaign, sent more than 24 hours ago. The stats are still the same.